# List made into a hash to compare generated pin code?

Tags: python, list, hash, equality

I am making a game where you crack a code. I want it so it can be any code from 0000 to 9999. I made this script.

```
from random import *
from time import sleep
pin = [randint(0,9),randint(0,9),randint(0,9),randint(0,9)]
print(pin)
usrinp = int(input(''))
if int(usrinp) == pin:
  print('cracked')
```

the trouble is when I input that code it doesn't work as in nothing comes out as an output. Is there a way to combine these 4 numbers to make a hash or whatever its called?

Comment: pin is a list of numbers

Comment: `hash(tuple(pin))`? But I don't see how that is related to your trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a list of integers, and are comparing it with a single integer. That doesn't work for two reasons:

- single integers are never equal to a list, whatever the contents
- `int()` doesn't preserve leading `0` characters; `int('0999')` returns `999`, `int('0000')` returns `0`.

Keep your input and your secret as *strings*, so you can keep the leading `0`. Make them both the same type, so generate a single string, not a list of integers.

Your secret pin can be generated by picking string digits:

```
digits = '0123456789'  # or use from string import digits

pin = ''.join([random.choice(digits) for _ in range(4)])  # 4 random digits, one string
```

then test the `input()` value against that pin:

```
usrinp = input('')
if usrinp == pin:
    # ...
```

Note: you *could* pick a single random integer too, with `random.randint(0, 9999)`, but that would make it harder for you to then to tell the player if they got *some* of the digits correct. By generating a string instead, you could, for example, trivially count how many digits they had correct:

```
if usrinp == pin:
    print('Cracked!')
else:
    correct_count = 0
    for pindigit, userdigit in zip(pin, usrinp):
        if pindigit == userdigit:
            correct_count += 1
    print('Sorry, not the right pin, but you guessed",
          correct_count, 'digits correctly!')
```

You can achieve the same with two integers, but then you'd have to use maths or string conversions to extract each digit and handle values with leading zeros correctly. It all becomes just that little bit more complicated.

Another alternative is to convert the user input to separate integers (so keep your original generated list of integers):

```
userinp = [int(digit) for digit in input('')]
```

but unless you also plan to use the digits in arithmetic (summing them, multiplying, etc.) there is no real advantage in that approach over using strings. Both lists and strings are sequences, but generating strings saves you from having to handle users that stubbornly enter `'Your mamma is a <censored>'` every time they play your game and break the `int()` conversions. :-)

None of this requires [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function); hashing is of no use here, because you want to test for equality, not trying to reduce a large amount of potential values to a limited set of options (like trying to put arbitrary values into a table of limited size, or to direct a large number of incoming connections to a limited number of servers that can handle those connections).

Comment: Maybe simpler to generate a random four digits number with `pin = randint(999,10000)`?

Comment: @Cendre: then you can't have a leading zero digit. `0000` is a valid PIN too!

Comment: a weak pin though but fair enough :)

Comment: @Cendre The probability of randomly guessing 0000 and a different 4 digit number is the same.

Comment: @Farhan.K: the probability that a human tries `0000` before trying `7452` is a lot higher. And we are talking about humans guessing here, not an automated script. And the probability that a programmer writing a cracker program would just start generating pin codes at `0000` are also higher than them using a random distribution for the guesses. :-)

Comment: @Farhan.K: which is why banks usually disallow `0000` as a pincode for bank cards, as well as consecutive digits (no sequences such as `2345`).

Comment: @Farhan.K: so no, the probability of randomly *guessing* 0000 and a different 4 digit number are **not** the same. Are you sure you are not thinking about the probability of *generating* such a number?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. Forgot that this is a human guessing :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are comparing an integer value with a list.

```
import random
from time import sleep
pin = 1000*randint(0, 9) + 100*randint(0, 9) + 10*randint(0, 9) + randint(0, 9)
print(pin)
usrinp = int(input(''))
if usrinp == pin:
  print('cracked')
```

this should work, if your pin always is going to be 4 digits, not for the ones with leading zeroes.

Comment: `pin = 1000*randint(0, 9) + 100*randint(0, 9) + 10*randint(0, 9) + randint(0, 9)` is this same as `pin = randint(0, 9999)`

Comment: No it's the same as `pin = randint(999,10000)` I think, with your code you can have 5 for instance

Comment: @Cendre 1000 * 9 + 100 * 9 + 10 * 9 + 1 * 9 = 9999

Answer (score 0):

To get a four digit int use this:

```
pin = randint(0, 9999)
```

So the resulting code would be:

```
from random import *
from time import sleep
pin = randint(0, 9999)
print('%04d'%pin)  # print with leading zeros
usrinp = int(input(''))
if usrinp == pin:
  print('cracked')
```